# Monotonicity of the Hellinger integral/distance

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, st.statistics

Let $p$ and $q$ be probability densities on $\mathbb R$, with respect to the Lebesgue measure $dx$. The corresponding Hellinger integral and distance are 
$H(p,q):=\int_{\mathbb R}\sqrt{pq}\,dx$ and $\rho(p,q):=\sqrt{\frac12\int_{\mathbb R}(\sqrt{p}-\sqrt q)^2\,dx}=\sqrt{1-H(p,q)}$.

For real $t$, define the $t$-shifted version $p_t$ of $p$ by the formula $p_t(x):=p(x-t)$ for real $x$. A general question is this: Are there broad conditions that guarantee that $H(p_0,p_t)$ will be nonincreasing in $t\ge0$?

A more specific question: if $p$ is unimodal (that is, nondecreasing to the left of some point $c$ and nonincreasing to the right of $c$), will it guarantee that $H(p_0,p_t)$ is nonincreasing in $t\ge0$? 
This is easy to see if $p$ is also assumed to be symmetric. Numerical experiments (with piecewise-constant $p$) suggest that the unimodality should be enough, even without the symmetry.

(Of course, for (say) saw-like $p$'s, we will not have the desired monotonicity.)

To put this into a context: if one has the strict version of the desired monotonicity, this will allow the convenient reparameterization $[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto\tau:=\rho(p_0,p_t)$ of the statistical parametric shift (location) family $(p_t)$ of densities.

Comment: Why don't you simply differentiate w.r.t. $t\geq 0$?

Comment: If the probability density is log-concave function then the claim is true. Indeed, $\sqrt{p(x)p(x+t)}$ is log-concave, then by Prekopa--Leindler $f(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sqrt{p(x)p(x+t)} dx$ is log-concave, and by change of variables $f(t)$ it is even. Therefore $f(t)$ is decreasing for $t\geq 0$. Actually this argument can be used to show that the claim is true  if $B(x,y)=p(x)q(y)$ is quasiconcave function.

Comment: leo: so, what should I do after the differentiation?

Comment: Paata: Your point about the log-concave case is very nice. However, in the problem from which my question came, the log-concave case can be easily tackled without reparameterization. 
Can you elaborate on the "quasiconcave" part of your comment? In particular, I don't know what you mean by $q$. In my question, I only have $p$ and its shifts $p_t$.

Comment: Iosif, I am sorry I meant $p(x)p(y)$ is quasiconcave. It was a typo in my previous comment. This case does not solve your conjecture for unimodal functions, but at least it covers some cases of it. Yes I will write details later because I am not with my computer.

Comment: Paata: Perhaps you meant to derive the quasiconcave case from the basic Brascamp--Lieb inequality (Theorem 3.1 in Journal of Functional Analysis **22**, 366-389 (1976)), using there $f=P_0$ and $g=P_t$, where $P:=\sqrt{pp_t}$ for $t\ge0$, so that (say) $P_{t/2}\ge h_{-\infty}$ (for $\lambda=1/2$). However, then the condition $\|f\|_\infty=\|g\|_\infty$ will not in general be satisfied for $t>0$.

Comment: Iosif: you are right it does not follow from the Brascamp--Lieb inequality  that if $h((x+y)/2)\geq \min\{f(x),h(y)\}$ then $\int h \geq \min\{\int f , \int g \}$. I had in mind different approach (the one that I have mentioned here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215274/identities-and-inequalities-in-analysis-and-probability/215389#215389) but I just realized that  it also does not work whenever I try to smooth the function $\min\{x,y\}$

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you figured it out by now, but I'll post it for the sake of completeness. Any unimodal $\sqrt{p}$ can be approximated by a sum $\sum c_k\chi_{I_k}$ with $I_1\subset I_2\subset\dots$. Now just notice that the function $\int(\chi_{I_k})(\chi_{I_j})_t$ is non-increasing in $t\ge 0$ for any $k,j$.